# ZeroMQ REQ .recv() hangs with messages larger than ~1kB if run inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm working on a relatively simple Python / ZeroMQ based work distribution system, using REQ/ROUTER sockets. The system is distributed and worker nodes are geographically distributed on different continents.

The `ROUTER`, responsible for distributing work, **`.bind()`**-s a `ROUTER` socket. Workers **`.connect()`** to it over TCP using a `REQ` socket.

In the process of setting up a new worker node, I've noticed that while smaller messages (up to 1kB) do the trip with no issues, replies of ~2kB and up, sent by the `ROUTER`-end are never received by the worker into their `REQ`-socket - when I call `recv()`, the socket just hangs.

The worker code runs inside Docker containers, and I was able to work around the issue when running the same image with `--net=host` - it seems to not happen if Docker is using the host network.

I'm wondering if this is something in the network stack configuration on the host machine or in Docker, or maybe something that can be prevented in my code?

Here is a simplified version of my code that reproduces this issue:

### Worker

```
import sys
import zmq
import logging
import time

READY = 'R'

def worker(connect_to):
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REQ)

    socket.connect(connect_to)
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    while True:
        socket.send_string(READY)
        log.debug("Send READY message, waiting for reply")
        message = socket.recv()
        log.debug("Got reply of %d bytes", len(message))
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    worker(sys.argv[1])
```

### Router

```
import sys
import zmq
import logging

REPLY_SIZE = 1024 * 8

def router(bind_to):
    ctx = zmq.Context()
    socket = ctx.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    socket.bind(bind_to)

    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    while True:
        socks = dict(poller.poll(5000))
        if socks.get(socket) == zmq.POLLIN:
            message = socket.recv_multipart()
            log.debug("Received message of %d parts", len(message))
            identity, _ = message[:2]
            res = handle_message(message[2:])
            log.debug("Sending %d bytes back in response on socket", len(res))
            socket.send_multipart([identity, '', res])


def handle_message(parts):
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log.debug("Got message: %s", parts)
    return 'A' * REPLY_SIZE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    router(sys.argv[1])
```

FWIW I was able to reproduce this on Ubuntu 16.04 (both router and worker) with Docker `17.09.0-ce`, libzmq `4.1.5` and PyZMQ `15.4.0`.

Comment: How do you run this in Docker? If you have a dockerfile to build the container, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

### No, sir, the socket does not hang at all:

Why?

The issue is, that you have instructed the **`Socket()`**-instance to enter into an infinitely blocking state, once having called **`.recv()`** method, without specifying a **`zmq.NOBLOCK`** flag ( the `ZMQ_DONTWAIT` flag in the ZeroMQ original API ).

This is the cause, that upon other circumstances reported yesterday, moves the code into infinite blocking, as there seem to be other issues that prevent Docker-container to properly deliver any first message to the hands of the Worker's Docker-embedded-ZeroMQ-`Context()` I/O-engine and to the hands of the **`REQ`**-access-point. As the **`REQ`**-archetype uses a strict two-step Finite-State-Automaton - strictly striding ( `.send()`->`.recv()`->`.send()`-> `...` ad infimum )

This cause->effect reversing is wrong and misleading -
the issue of "***socket just hangs***"
is **un-decideable**
from an issue **Docker does not deliver a single message** ( to allow `.recv()` to return )

---

### Next steps:

may use **`.poll()`** in **`REQ`**-side to sniff without blocking for any already arrived message in the Worker.

Once there are none such, **focus on Docker first** + next may benefit from ZeroMQ **`Context()`**-I/O-engine performance and link-level tweaking configuration options.

Comment: Maybe my phrasing is not clear enough. I think it's pretty obvious that something in the way the Docker network works or is configured on that machine causes the message to never reach it's destination. I'm perfectly fine with `recv()` blocking - that's like that by design.

Comment: Well, yes and no, Shahar. Your yesterday posted text confirmed, that < 1 kB messages did get through, which makes the problem not isolated to just a Docker container-setup, but has added also some other unclear system-behaviour dependencies. I advocate, wherever I can, not to enter into any blocking state, as there you have lost any and all means of control and just left your code accidentally-hanging in the breezes of external events, to which your code principally can't respond, till a very specific case **no error was in transport && a-message-got-sent** which is **too risky to rely on**